# C++ overloaded [] operator with sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have class called Vector which contains dynamic array with numbers. But array must be always sorted. I have a few methods like `changeSize`, `addElement`, etc. but the only problem is overloaded array operator. It must return particular number to read or write. This is my code:

```
double &Vector::operator[](unsigned index) {
if (!length || index > length - 1) {
    std::fputs("Vector::operator[]: invalid index!", stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
return vector[index];
}
```

Everything works fine but this mothod breaks sorted principal. For example:

```
Vector vector(2);
vector[0] = 1.2;
```

In this case I am changing value outside the function and can't have sorted elements. Is any way to do this with [] operator?

Comment: Return proxy object which will alert vector if the element gets modified.

Comment: @Incomputable There's just one problem with that: Unless well-documented then the users of the `Vector` class might be surprised when the elements gets reorganized, and the element just set no longer is what's expected. To the OP: Naming is important. I suggest you rename your class to e.g. `SortedVector`. And disallow direct modifications of the elements, i.e. only make the `operator[]` function return a *value* instead of a reference.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, also auto will not work as expected, and IIRC it will violate container constraints set by the standard, so it won’t be usable with standard library.

Comment: It has a hint of bad design. With the constraints you're putting on the vector, it feels weird to allow modifications with `[ ]` at all.

Comment: What do you want to happen in the example you gave? Can you just use std::multiset<double> or only sort when necessary? Can you change the interface to disallow operations that don't make sense? Also, there is a partially sorted data structure (heap aka priority_queue) which is far superior for some algorithms, but I don't know what you are using this for.